# OpenWRT router bash scipt issue

Tags: bash, startup

I want run a bash scrip at boot. However I have an error. What is wrong with my script ? when I send the string from command line, I get no error. Is it a problem with variables inside of the bash script ? The code I shared was working on my other project.

anybody can help me ?

**script**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQef3.png)

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
# Example script

START=40

start() {

    file="ipcam.txt"

    while IFS=: read -r xf1 xf2 xf3
    do
        printf 'Loop: %s %s %s\n' "$xf1" "$xf2" "$xf3"
        f1=$xf1
        f2=$xf2
        f3=$xf3
    done < "$file"
    printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"


    echo "script start"
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $f2 -j DNAT --to-destination $f1:$f3
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text, it makes it difficult for people to both search and copy-paste to try to help you.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45103825/edit) your question with the text (formatted as code preferably) instead of the image

Comment: Don't you want for `#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common` to be split onto two lines, and that you are sourcing the file, i.e. `.  /etc/rc.common` ? Good luck.

Comment: it is a syntax for openwrt.   #!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First (should have been a comment perhaps) "I have an error" is generally a bad description; you should add what the error is.
The most obvious error  is:

```
file="ipcam.txt"
```

This will look for `ipcam.txt` in the current directory. It may be in the directory where you test the script, but it probably is not in the directory when the script is run at start-up. The remedy would be to put the full pathname (`/etc/ipcam.txt` or wherever you put it) in the script.